# Upload to server from Android gives error response the whole php Script

Tags: php, android, xml

I am having a problem with uploading XML file to web server from my android application. I tried to debug but the whole PHP script is printed on Eclipse LogCat when the debug reaches:

> Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);

I am not sure if the PHP script is correct. For Instance I am not aware if I have to add the file name (Coords.xml) on the PHP script as well. The code I am using to upload the XML file on the server is:

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                    DataOutputStream dos = null;
                    DataInputStream inStream = null;
                    String existingFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Coords.xml";
                    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                    String twoHyphens = "--";
                    String boundary = "*****";
                    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                    byte[] buffer;
                    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                    String responseFromServer = "";
                    String urlString = "http://MyWebSiteName/php/upload1.php";

                    try {

                        //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(existingFileName));
                        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                        URL url = new URL(urlString);
                        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        // Allow Inputs
                        conn.setDoInput(true);
                        // Allow Outputs
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);
                        // Don't use a cached copy.
                        conn.setUseCaches(false);
                        // Use a post method.
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + existingFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        // create a buffer of maximum size
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                        // read file and write it into form...
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        while (bytesRead > 0) {

                            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        }

                        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
                        // close streams
                        Log.e("Debug", "File is written");
                        fileInputStream.close();
                        dos.flush();
                        dos.close();

                    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                    }

                    //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
                    try {

                        inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                        String str;

                        while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {

                            Log.e("Debug", "Server Response " + str);

                        }

                        inStream.close();

                    } catch (IOException ioex) {
                        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);


                    }
```

The PHP Script is:

```
    < ?php

   $file_path = "/uploads";

   $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
       echo "success";
   } else{
       echo "fail";
   }
? >
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can't just dump code in here and say: why does not work. Or how would that work. Instead pin-point the actual question you'd like to ask. E.g. what is the first part you *know* that you don't understand with all the technologies involved. Go back to that place, then ask about it. Show that you know to which internet standards you're relating to by naming the correct terms and standrad names / numbers (e.g. RFC 123 etc.).

Comment: Also properly format your code. As you paste code-examples from your live-code (instead you should create a new example from scratch that just demonstrates your issue which you're perhaps just too far off), you need to explain why you wrote that code exactly this way. Explain for each line of code why you did it that way. And mark exactly the parts about which you are not sure.